# Task serialization issue when using SparkML prediction model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I get Task serialization error when running this code, where `myDstream` is `DStream[String]` and `session` is `String`:

```
      val model = GradientBoostedTreesModel.load(sc,mySet.value("modelAddress") + mySet.value("modelId"))
      val newDstream = myDstream.map(session => {
        val features : Array[String] = UtilsPredictor.getFeatures()
        val parsedSession = UtilsPredictor.parseJSON(session)
        var input: String = ""
        var count: Integer = 1
        for (i <- 0 until features.length) {
          if (count < features.length) {
            input += parsedSession(features(i)) + ","
            count += 1
          }
          else {
            input += parsedSession(features(i))
          }
        }
        input = "[" + input + "]"
        val vecTest = Vectors.parse(input)
        parsedSession + ("prediction_result" -> model.predict(vecTest).toString)
      })


      newDstream.foreachRDD(session => {
        session.foreachPartition({ partitionOfRecords =>
            //...
        })
      })
```

The object `UtilsPredictor` is serializable. The problem deals with the usage of prediction model.
But the most strange thing is that the serialization error is triggered by the line `newDstream.foreachRDD(session => {`. Any ideas how to avoid this error?

UPDATE:

I tried `@transient val vectTest = Vectors.parse(input`, however again get the same Task serialization error. Below I provide the error message. In particular, the error is triggered by the line `Predictor.scala:234` which is `session.foreachPartition({ partitionOfRecords =>`:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.test.classifier.Predictor$$anonfun$run$2.apply(Predictor.scala:234)
    at org.test.classifier.Predictor$$anonfun$run$2.apply(Predictor.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
```

Comment: It seems to me that the issue is likely to be in the code you've elided (`//...`) since you've said that part of the code triggers it, and it's the body of the `foreach` that is being serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure your class is `extends Serializable`
- Add `@transient` to the block of code which you suspect that it gives task serialization error.This annotation will skip the particular entity from calculating/considering for serialization.

Generally that is what we do when we write logging in the application as given below

```
 @transient private lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)
```

Comment: Do you mean this? ` @transient private lazy val newDstream = myDstream.map(session => {`

Comment: is ur class extends Serializable?

Comment: try with his 
@transient val parsedSession = UtilsPredictor.parseJSON(session).

Comment: Yes, `UtilsPredictor` extends serializable. The problem is not caused by `UtilsPredictor`. The problem is related to `model.predict`. Though `GradientBoostedTreesModel` is serializable, `vecTest` (it is `String`) is not. So, if I follow your logic, I should do `@transient val vecTest = ...`. Right? Let me test it.

Comment: yeah.give a try

Comment: I tested your solution, however I have the same error. Could you please take a look at my update, where I posted the whole error message. It seems that `model.predict` actually works, however the error happens later at the line `session.foreachPartition({ partitionOfRecords =>`. Seems like `session` is not serializable. Really misunderstand this point.

Comment: hmm. is ter any chance to make session serializable ? is that your own implementation or any API's?